# What is the recomended application set for QA/tester's suite in Ubuntu?

Tags: testing, quality, testsuite

I work in SQA as Test manager/Tester and I want to get more from my Ubuntu desktop. Unfortunately Ubuntu does not have much software in repository for this task. Can you recommend set of Linux applications a software tester should have and eventually how to install it?

Comment: Dee, help me understand a bit more of what your asking ;-) Are you wondering what tools you can use to do software testing that run on ubuntu? Or are you asking what software testing is being done on ubuntu?

Comment: L- As I already wrote I work in SQA, so thats clear i want to use Ubuntu in my job... but missing the software testers usually use from simple screen picture grabber with editor to point on error trough log readers, service probes and diagraming tools to test planning tools. I expect this will have lot of correct solutions. With such missing set of applications in my test suite, I can easily find myself to running Windows in Virtualbox to do my job.

Comment: The bounty offered cannot be "divided between 1-5 valuable answers"; it always has to go to just one answer; see the notes on the [FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/privileges/set-bounties).

Comment: Official tools available are the `ubuntu-dev-tools`, but I don't know whether that's what you are looking for.

Comment: @Dee: there are dozen of tools for QA. As you already know, QA is a pretty big field. Probably you should edit your question specifying what tools you are exactly looking for and why you need them. For example: you said you need a log reader. Isn't a simple text editor enough? If not, why? Without knowing what you are going to work on and **how** you are going to work, it's very difficult to provide an answer.

Comment: @Andrea: without being a tester (practical experience) it is hard to imagine what is necessary and I do not recommend to anybody to answer if you don't have practical experience as a software tester who uses Ubuntu in his/her job. / What I'm trying to achieve is a list of apps a tester should have in his/her linux without suffering of search/try/remove cycles.

Comment: @Dee: I work on testing, QA, and bug triaging in Ubuntu. [Here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-bugcontrol/ubuntu-qa-tools/master/files) are some of the tools used by the Ubuntu QA team. I'm sure you'll find nothing useful there, for the simple reason that you are working on a project different from Ubuntu. Different projects need different tools.

Comment: @andrea: Yea, thats right, I do not need increase quality of Ubuntu, but use Linux (Ubuntu) in my daily QA job on other projects.

Comment: Given the lack of specifics; here's a random list of stuff that you might find interesting.

valgrind, strace, pts, autopilot, sikuli, xpresser, xunit, mago/ldtp

Comment: /Agree with the majority of comments on here so far.  Consider editing your original question, and clarify exactly what type of software you're testing, and/or what sort of 'tests' you're running.

Are you simply using telnet/ssh into another system remotely?  Are you testing a local database application?  Are you testing a back-end process that communicates to/receives data from another system?  What all are you trying to test?

- (also in QA for many years)

Comment: @ balloons, yes, that is what i search for, strace, pts, sikuli, xunit, mago are the excellent examples of tester's tools, which should be installed in tester's ubuntu. valgrind and xunit is more for developer's suite, but ok, touches quality. I expected this as an answer, not a comment. Actually, i expected more than zero answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have been away from QA since 2007, and was at the time working with windows.  So needless to say at the time I did not think much of any tools that would run under Linux.  So I've done some research, and I found many tools that can be used.

> ABI Compliance Checker.  A tool for checking backward binary
>   compatibility of a shared C/C++ library. It analyzes changes in API
>   that may cause compatibility problems: changes in call stack, v-table
>   changes, removed interfaces, etc.
>
> Autonet.  Autonet is a GUI network test platform, internally it's
>   based on CLI to communicate with devices. It can help you to arrange
>   test cases, setup commands to devices ,run commands to check results
>   and record test results.
>
> Doit: Simple Web Application Testing.  Doit is a scripting tool and
>   language for testing web applications that use forms. Doit can
>   generate random or sequenced form fill-in information, report results
>   (into a database, file, or stdout), filter HTML results, and compare
>   results to previous results, without having to manually use a web
>   browser. It uses a console-based web client tool (like Curl or Wget)
>   to send and receive HTTP requests and responses respectively.
>
> PETA.  Eclipse-based platform for automated software testing and
>   covers the software life cycle from the specification up to the
>   maintenance phase. The components of message based software systems
>   like Client-/Server-, Multitier- and Service-Oriented-Architectures
>   (SOA) may be simulated as well as tested in isolation and in their
>   supposed interaction.

And others too many to list.  Most of these tools will run under Linux, and I will include these links, that will give all the information that you need ( description, platform, download location, and installation procedure).

Sources and Links:

[Open Source Testing](http://www.opensourcetesting.org/functional.php)

[Aptest](http://www.aptest.com/resources.html)

[Software Testing Help](http://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/performance-testing-tools-load-testing-tools/)

[Software Testing Software](http://www.softwaretestingsoftware.com/software-testing-tools/)

[Indiangnu](http://www.indiangnu.org/2011/top-5-open-source-software-testing-qa-tools/)

Comment: +bounty. Unfortunatelly there is not possible to assign bounty to a comment.

Comment: from PETA I have found good Testmanagement tool witw Community edition named Claros, good...

Answer (score 0):

I personally used (updated)

- SOAP-UI: http://sourceforge.net/projects/soapui/files/soapui/ installable trough download and shell script
- Selenium IDE (firefox plugin)
- XML Copy editor
- Hotshots (screenshots) - http://sourceforge.net/projects/hotshots/
- terminal + tail: log reader

I was trying:

- Eclipse 4 testing: http://www.eclipse.org/tptp/
- Swatch: log reader - http://swatch.sourceforge.net/
- Multitail: yet another log reader - http://www.vanheusden.com/multitail/